# PowerShell Recycling bin size Get-ChildItem issues

Tags: powershell, code

Im a bit lost. Been working on a script to check the size of the C and if less then 20 Gig, notify me and get usual suspect folder sizes. Been using Get-ChildItem for Deskp, Docs, Music, etc. but having issues with the bin.

When I run,

```
    Get-ChildItem C:\ -Hidden -force
```

[Get-ChildItem C results w/ -hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcwiy.png)

but $Recycle.Bin and several other seem to not show file size. Had seen several long codes that people have made on gethub but there must be a sorter way.

Also when I run,

```
Get-ChildItem C:\$RECYCLE.BIN
```

PS can't find the path. I take it the $ makes it a variable and don't want to change each user's bin name as a work around.

Comment: Wrap it in `""`

Comment: Ah, thanks! Didn't think to use that, thought it was for spaces only.

Comment: @spikey_richie So I am able to view it now with,  Get-ChildItem C:\'$RECYCLE.BIN' -Hidden but seems I have been barking up the wrong tree this whole time as it shows only when it was last emptied, know of a better cmdlet to get the size of the bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following will get the sum of the `.Length` properties of the files in the recycle bin ...

```
(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\$Recycle.Bin' -File -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
```

output [in bytes, on my system, today] = 249852365

what it does ...

- grabs the files from the recycle bin
  the single quotes around the path name prevent PoSh from trying to expand the `$Recycle`. [*grin*]
- the `Measure-Object` grabs all the `.Length` properties & sums them
- the final `.Sum` grabs just that value from the output of `M-O`

Comment: Lee, thank you again! I will have to add a note at the bottom of my script for all the help you have given me on this multi-parter. Those ' ' and "" really through me through a loop sometimes. Thanks again.

Comment: @XXLMandalorian - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]